# WSO2, What is the Proxy URL by which I can Invoke WSO2 in my Application

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

My published app

```
https://localhost:9443/publisher/info?Name=weatherapi&version=1.0.0&provider=admin
```

Host   -  localhost
Port   -  9443

Note  :-  I am using standalone WSO2 API manager

I subscribed the Weather API app and generated consumer key, consumer secret and access token.

Sandbox URLs:
When I fire a request , using WSO2 API console

```
curl -x get --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: bearer a3eb309dd898241469e4b058a1501520" "Https://100.68.70.149:8243/weatherapi/1.0.0/?Q=London"
```

I am getting the proper response.

I am confused, which url to point, in my application to avail the facility of deployed app (weather-api).

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please elaborate bit more!

Comment: use camel case, not all upper case

Answer (score 1):

9443 Port is the servlet port which will be used to invoke Admin Services etc.
When it comes to API invocations default 8280(http) and 8243(https) ports will be used. So you need to use 8280 for API invocations